# NextJs+SupabaseJS - Trying to use getStaticProps() gives undefined props in the page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

In the default NextJS page.js (so Javascript), i'm trying to use getStaticProps() for because i've a lot of multiple database(Supabase) fetches and with "standard" render it returns only a part of the data, not all.
That's what i'm trying to do (i've a main object called `features` where i want to put all the fetched data, then i would like to pass to a client component).
This is the code in the `app/page.js` component:

```
import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/page';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
  const { data: {session} } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
  // console.log(session)
  if (!session) {
    return redirect('/components/login')
  }

  var features = {}
  let { data } = await supabase.from("profili").select().eq('id', session.user.id).limit(1);
  const utente = data[0];
  if (utente.role === 'role1' || utente.role === 'role2') {
    let { data } = await supabase.from("list1").select().order('created_at', {ascending: false});
    features.list1 = data;
  } else {
    features.list1 = null;
  }

  if (utente.role === 'role2' || utente.role === 'role3') {
    let { data } = await supabase.from("list2").select().order('created_at', {ascending: false});
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      data.forEach( async (userData, index) => {
        supabase
          .from("other_list")
          .select()
          .eq("id", userData.profile_id)
          .limit(1).then((val) => {
            data[index].doc= val.data[0].nome
            if (index === data.length-1) {
              resolve();
            }
          })
      })
      
    }).then((res) => {
      features.list2 = data;
    })
  } else {
    features.list2 = null;
  }

  if (utente.role === 'role3' || utente.role === 'role4') {
    let { data } = await supabase.from("list3").select().order('created_at', {ascending: false});
    features.list3 = data;
  } else {
    features.list3 = null;
  }

  return {
    props: {
      features,
      session
    },
    fallback: true,
    revalidate: 10
  }
}


export default function Home({ features, session}) {
  console.log(features, session)
  return  (
    <Dashboard session={session} features={features}  />
  )
}
```

In those code almost 1 of the subobjects into features has a value and others are set of null (for me that ok for because i use the null value to render something else).
The problem is for list 2, where i've to update the data object to something else retrieved from an other Database table. And this retrieved data is not put into the features.list2 object (it gots only the first data object).
That's why i'm trying to use the getStaticProps().

But the in the Home(...) function features and session, are undefined.

In the getStaticProps() i tried to return also:

```
return {
    props: {
      ...features,
      ...session
    },
    fallback: true,
    revalidate: 10
  }
```

or

```
return {
    props: {
      features: await Promise.all(features),
      session
    },
    fallback: true,
    revalidate: 10
  }
```

but nothing changes